# Ampersand like symbol latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the name of this symbol, and how to make it in latex ?

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: Nice tool, thank you @Werner, But I can't find it there (or I draw bad)

Comment: ...and you looked through the possible math fonts listed in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive)?

Comment: On the page suggested by Werner there was a link to the online site http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @Werner I don't even know the symbol's name, it's a little bit hard to look for it just visually.

Comment: Have you got list of symbols from this book? It may be simply a calligraphic  S with subscript diag (as diagonal), but some larger material is needed to prove or disprove it.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the symbol ... where did you find it, what does it denote? Without further context I tend to agree with Przemysław Scherwentke that it is probably a calligraphic S.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a mathematical symbol, it's definitely a capital S, but in cursive. That's how it usually appears when you write by hand and in some fonts, depending on the style, it really looks like a flipped ampersand.

If you go to any website that provides fonts, search for "cursive font", and type a capital S. Some of them will look like the letter you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used to achieve the D'Nealian type, cursive S that looks like a backwards ampersand, &.
In the preamble:

`\usepackage{graphicx}    %this enables \rotatebox and \reflectbox`

then,
`$\reflectbox{\&}$`

the `\` preceding the ampersand is not needed for most letters and characters.  It's needed here as without the `\`, LaTeX 'thinks' you are invoking an alignment tab function.

Comment: So I apparently committed a faux pas.  @Chris H edited it, which if fine with me.  However I'd like to know how to better post next time.   Essentially now everything between "preamble:" and "then," after "then," and a few back slashes in the remainder of the text are now highlighted.  Someone tell me how to do it correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're on the desktop site, there's a code markup button (pair of curly brackets) above the text input box. If you're on mobile, you have to just know that backticks around text mark it as code. There are plenty of other formatting tools.

Comment: I don't yet 'do' mobile.  My phone still has a hinge.  So, I 'initiated' a new Ask Question.  When i clicked the { }, it placed a gray box in the text editor box.  I just paste my code in the gray box.  Correct?